# WUBI - Super Block Error

Tags: wubi

We had installed ubuntu 10.04 using Wubi on my machine. After a reboot it stopped working. Its says super block corrupted

Is there any tool or how can I get my data from the Ubuntu OS which is already installed on my mahcine

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything already installed that can access the disk. [This tool](http://ext2read.blogspot.ca/) can be used from Windows to get readonly access to the `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` but you may have issues if there is file system corruption.

You should boot from an Ubuntu CD/USB in live mode (select "Try Ubuntu") and fsck the root.disk as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_my_Wubi_install_and_repair_my_install_if_it_won.27t_boot.3F). For example, if your root.disk is on /dev/sda1 you would (change /dev/sda1 as appropriate):

1. Boot a live CD/USB
2. Mount the Windows partition

   `sudo mkdir /media/win`

   `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/win`
3. Fsck the root.disk

   `sudo fsck /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk`

Don't fsck the root.disk if it's mounted.

PS for Wubi it's important not to do hard resets. See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Warning).